# Using bicep to add a second domain to an existing Azure Security Policy

Tags: azure-bicep, azure-front-door, azure-waf

I need to add a security policy to a front door endpoint. I am using the following bicep.

```
resource security_policies 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/securitypolicies@2022-11-01-preview' = {
  parent: fdprofile
  name: securityPolicyName
  properties: {
    parameters: {
      wafPolicy: {
        id: waf.id
      }
      associations: [
        {
          domains: [
            {
              id: fdEndpoint.id
            }
          ]
          patternsToMatch: [
            '/*'
          ]
        }
      ]
      type: 'WebApplicationFirewall'
    }
  }
}
```

This works the first time I use it. It creates the security policy, links it to the waf policy, and associates it with the domain.

The problem is when I run this a second domain. I want to use the same security policy, and this time it associates it with the second domain. It appears this is replacing the associations, which has the effect of removing the policy from the first domain.

- When deploying, I am using incremental mode.
- Using the UI, I can add multiple domains to the same security policy.
  I need to do this with a IaC approach.
- This executes when assigning a new app service to front door. This deployment does not have knowledge of the other app services.

How can I use the bicep to add another domain, without losing the domains that are already there?

Comment: the `domains` property accept an array so you should be able to pass the existing values

Comment: I don't know the existing value. They are created my othr deployments. I am trying to add a new domain to an existing security policy.  Should I get them all and build an array, then send it to my bicep?

Comment: yeah that should work i think

Comment: **Typo alert**: it's a **domain** - not a "domian" (as you typed repeatedly...)

Comment: @Thomas that sort of works, unless it's the first one and the security policy doesn't exist.  Then using the existing resourec to pull the domain gives an error. I can't create a start policy with no domain. How can I get around the 'requested resource was not found' error?